# How to test @Configuration and @Bean in a Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I'm new to Spring Boot. I need to write JUnit test cases for the below class.
What is the efficient way to write a unit test case for @Configuration and @Bean annotation?

```
@Configuration
public class ABCConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private AwsApplicationProperties AwsApplicationProperties;
    List<AmazonSNS> amazonSNSClientArray = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @Bean
    public List<AmazonSNS> amazonSnsClient() {
      //some code here
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AWSCredentialsProvider aWSCredentials(String awsAccessKeyId, String awsSecretKeyId) {        
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretKeyId));
    }
}
```

Can some one help? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using ContextConfiguration and injecting ApplicationContext or injecting directly your beans @Autowired AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentials as properties.
Example below uses ApplicationContext directly.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ABCConfig.class })
class ABCConfigUnitTest {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    void givenImportedBeans_whenGettingEach_shallFindIt() {
        assertThatBeanExists("aWSCredentials", AWSCredentialsProvider.class);
    }

    private void assertThatBeanExists(String beanName, Class<?> beanClass) {
        Assertions.assertTrue(context.containsBean(beanName));
        Assertions.assertNotNull(context.getBean(beanClass));
    }
}
```